# React: Mapping an array of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to map data that I have in an array, however, the data is not mapped when I run the code. If I log the data (serials variable), it logs the variables that I would like to map (screenshot below). Does anyone have any suggestions about why the data isn't mapped?

```
numberList() {
  const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    const serialRef = db.ref(uid + "/serials");
    
    serialRef.on("value", (serial_numbers)=> {
      const serials = [];
      serial_numbers.forEach((serial_number)=> {
        serials.push({s:serial_number.val()});
      });
      console.log(serials);
  return (
    <ul>
      {serials.map((number) => <li>{number}</li>)};
    </ul>
  );
    });

}
        render (){
        return (
          <button onClick={this.numberList}>Cards</button>
        )};

}
```

[image: Screenshot of the data]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: > the data is not mapped when I run the code
how did you notice this?

Comment: When I click on the button the list doesn't appear on the page.

Answer (score 1):

From your `log` I assume the map should be as below to get exact number.

```
 return (
    <ul>
      {serials.map((number) => <li>{number.s.serial}</li>)};
    </ul>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it still doesn't show the values when I click the button, only the array gets logged in the console.

Answer (score 1):

The "numbers" you are mapping are objects (according to the log you attached), but React JS doesn't allow to display objects directly - you probably only want to display the value anyway. You should also include a key when generating a view from an array of objects. The correct code should be this:

```
<ul>
      {serials.map((number, i) => <li key={i}>{number.s.serial}</li>)};
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the list of data still doesn't appear on the page when I clik the button.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is it a blank screen or are other elements rendered?